# Is there a way to apply selector icon on Popupmenu?

Tags: android, xml

I want to show my Popupmenu with icons, but not just a ordinary icon, it's a icon with selector.

But it seems Selector is only apply to Button, Textview or sth.

Is there a alternative, or am I doing wrong?

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:title="foo"
        android:id="@+id/foo_menu"
        android:icon="@drawable/imgbtn_states"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />
</menu>
```

@drawable/imgbtn_states is a Selector.

This is `@drawable/imgbtn_states`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check"
        android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/uncheck"
        android:state_selected="false"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CheckedTextView instead of TextView, It can have both drawable and checkmark simultaneously.

Example :

```
<CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/item_checkk"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Item"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:checkMark="@drawable/check_mark"
        android:drawablePadding="15dp"/>
```

for CheckMark create check_mark.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_check_black"
            android:state_checked="true" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_uncheck_white"
            android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

In your Activity,

```
class Activity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sof)

        var isChecked = checked_textView.isChecked

        checked_textView.setOnClickListener {
            if(isChecked){
               checked_textView.isChecked  =false
               isChecked = false
            }else{
               checked_textView.isChecked  =true
               isChecked = true
         }
      }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.